# Python - Logic for Buy X get cheapest free in shopping basket

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

We have an offer of buying 3 shampoos and getting the cheapest free with any of the following:

```
d = {'Shampoo (Small)' : 2.00,
    'Shampoo (Medium)' : 2.50,
    'Shampoo (Large)' : 3.50}
```

Given that the basket contains:

```
basket_3 = {'Shampoo (Large)' : 3,
            'Shampoo (Medium)' : 1,
            'Shampoo (Small)': 2}
```

The answer should be:

```
sub-total: £17.0
discount: £5.5
total: 11.5
```

The customer has got 1 large and 1 small shampoo for free.

What I have tried to do was implement a function to find out which of the shampoos to get for free

```
def basket(basket):
    # calculates subtotal from function
    print("Subtotal: ","%.2f" % subtotal(basket))
    print("Discount: ","%.2f" % (subtotal(basket) - discounted(basket)))
    print("Total: ","%.2f" % discounted(basket))
    return basket

def subtotal(basket):
    d = {}
    for item,qty in basket.items():
        price = data[item]
        d[item]=(qty*price)
    return sum(d.values())

def discounted(basket):
    basket = offers(basket)
    d = {}
    for item,qty in basket.items():
        price = data[item]
        d[item]=(qty*price)
    return sum(d.values())

def offers(basket):
    d = {}
    for item,qty in basket.items():
        if 'Shampoo' in item:
            qty = shampoo(qty)
            d[item]=qty
        else:
            d.update({item:qty})        
    return d

def shampoo(purchased, buy=3, free=1):
    pack = buy - free
    buy_packs = purchased // pack
    buy_individual = purchased % pack
    return buy * buy_packs + buy_individual
```

But my result is

```
Subtotal:  17.00
Discount:  -5.50
Total:  22.50
```

Which got the discount right but the total should have been lower than the subtotal.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `shampoo` function doesn't seem to be computing quantities right. It is currently returning 4 items for `Shampoo (Large)`, 1 item for `Shampoo (Medium)` and 3 items for `Shampoo (Small)`. What is the logic behind `buy * buy_packs + buy_individual `? The problem is most likely in that function.

As a result `discounted(basket)` is returning 22.5 which doesn't make sense, because it shouldn't be bigger than `subtotal`

Comment: I got it from another stackoverflow answer so not sure. Do you know how to fix it? @Turtlean

Comment: I have a question regarding the offer: 1 Shampoo (Large) is for free because you're buying 3 of those, right? And in the other case is 1 Shampoo (Small) for free because you're grouping the remaining 2 Mediums + 1 Small (and therefore the small is the cheapest)?

Comment: Yes, that's what the OP claims. I can see how that works now. Still the code looks like everything is upside down.

Comment: Yeah you got it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite the whole `shampoo` function to:

```py
def shampoo(purchased, buy=3, free=1):
    buy_packs = purchased // buy
    return purchased - free * (buy_packs)
```

This makes much more sense to me, especially because of the named arguments `buy` and `free` which I interpret as: "Every `buy` units, `free` should be free".

By applying those changes, `buy_packs` variable now computes: "How many groups of size `buy` does the purchase have? So `free` * `buy_packs` will compute the number of free items that we should take from `purchased`

#### Caveats

> getting the cheapest free with any of the following

However, neither the current change nor the original codebase takes the `cheapest` product into account to compute the offers.

The proof is that the `offer` function is just looking for the substring `"Shampoo"` in the item's name. So it isn't sorting the Shampoo products (Large, Medium, Small) according to their price. It's using the initial order of the basket entries.

In the same direction, current changes (and I'm pretty sure the original codebase either) don't support applying offers over two different groups. Given the original example:

```py
basket_3 = {'Shampoo (Large)' : 3,
            'Shampoo (Medium)' : 1,
            'Shampoo (Small)': 2}
```

The algorithm will start with `Shampoo (Large)` and will ask:
"Does this group has `3` items or more?". "Oh yeah, so 1 should be free".
Then, it'll go on with the next group `Shampoo (Medium)` and will ask the same question again, so the answer will be: "Nope. There's only 1 item". Finally, it'll go through the final group `Shampoo (Small)` and the answer will again be: ""Nope. There's are only 2 items", completely forgetting about the previous group and incapable of realizing that 1 item from the previous plus 2 from the current are enough to give 1 item for free.

Required changes to support that feature are definitely more complex than the current codebase.

Comment: spot on! can you explain what the function does exactly?

Comment: Srry @a.r.noureldin I found a mistake in my answer. I'm trying to fix it so it makes sense, but the problem is definitely in the `shampoo` function

Comment: @a.r.noureldin does the changes to the original answer make sense to you? I wholly rewrote the `shampoo` function because I found it very difficult to understand

Comment: I took the explanation further =). Good luck!